# Process boolean phrase with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am processing user input on a search page. If the user selects an 'All Words' type search, then I remove any boolean search operators from the search text and stick `' AND '` between each real word. Pretty simple in most cases. However, I can't figure out how to remove two boolean operators in a row.

Here is my code:

```
// create the regex
private static Regex _cleaner =
     new Regex("(\\s+(and|or|not|near)\\s+)|\"", 
          RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// call the regex
_cleaner.Replace(searchText, " ")
```

The problem occurs when a user enters a search string like `coffee and not tea`. The regex will remove the 'and', but not the 'not'. The resulting string is 'coffeenot tea' - what I want is 'coffee tea'.

The white space is required in the regex so I don't remove 'and', 'or', etc when embedded in real words (like 'band' or 'corps').

I have temporarily resolved this by calling the clean method twice, which will remove two operators in a row (which is probably all I would ever need). But it is not very elegant, is it? I would really like to do it right. I feel like I am missing something simple...

Comment: Your regex will fail on "not coffee and tea", which is the same thing as "tea and not coffee".

Comment: @Yurij - yes - that is handled elsewhere

Comment: @Jim - thanx for the heads up - the answer from MRAB fixes that problem too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding word boundaries:

```
"\\b(and|or|not|near)\\b|\""
```

Comment: That was it - I knew it was something "obvious" - thanx for your help

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to the following:

```
private static Regex _cleaner = new Regex("(\\s+(and|or|not|near)\\s+)*|\"", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't just adding a `+` fix the problem?

```
private static Regex _cleaner = 
    new Regex("(\\s+(and|or|not|near)\\s+)+|\"", 
              RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// call the regex
_cleaner.Replace(searchText, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not matching because you require whitespace on each side of your term, but since it's not `_and__not_`, you only match `_and_`.

Consider this regex:

```
@"(?:and|or|not|near)\s+|"""
```